# SQL Server CREATE AGGREGATE logic error

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlclr

I've created a CLR funtion for SQL Server 2014 that should calculate subtraction between the first and the last value in column `[Value]`.

Here is the table:

```
 Date_Time                    Value
 -------------------------------------
 2018-03-29 09:30:02.533      6771
 2018-03-29 10:26:23.557      6779
 2018-03-29 13:12:04.550      6787
 2018-03-29 13:55:44.560      6795
```

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  
using System.Data.SqlTypes;  
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;  

[Serializable]  
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.Native,  
                         IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,  
                         IsInvariantToNulls = true,  
                         IsInvariantToOrder = false,  
                         IsNullIfEmpty = true,  
                         Name = "SUBT")]  
public struct SUBT  
{  
 private double first;  
 private double last;  
 private int count;  

 public void Init()  
 {  
      first = 0.0;  
      last  = 0.0;  
      count = 0;  
 }  

 public void Accumulate(SqlDouble Value)  
 {  
    if (!Value.IsNull)  
    {  
        if (count == 0) 
            first = (double)Value;
        else 
            last = (double)Value;

        count += 1;  
    }  
 }  

 public void Merge(SUBT Group)  
 {  
    first = Group.first;
    last = Group.last;
    count += 1;  
 }  

 public SqlDouble Terminate()  
 {  
      double value = (double)(last - first);  
      return new SqlDouble(value);  
 }  
}
```

So the result should be `[Value]=24`, i.e. 6795 - 6771, but I get 6795 :(

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This aggregate function is dependent on order but there is no ordering guarantee for the aggregation input stream. Consequently, the results are execution plan dependent.

Assuming the `Date_Time` value is the desired ordering, you could provide both `Date_Time` and `Value` as function arguments, save the value with the lowest and highest `Date_time` values and use those in the `Merge` and `Terminate` methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here, I believe:

1. In the `Merge` method you are making two bad assumptions:

   1. You are assuming that the incoming `Group` has a value, yet it could have been called on one or more `NULL` values, in which case all 3 internal variables are `0`. Yet you are overwriting the current values of `first` and `last`, which could have non-`0` values prior to `Merge` being called, but then will end up back at `0` due to being overwritten.
   2. You are assuming that at least one of the instances — the current one or the incoming `Group` — has values set (i.e. has been called at least once on a non-`NULL` value). In the case that both instances have only been called with a `NULL` value, you will have `0` for `first` and `last`, yet you will increment `counter`. I am not sure if `Accumulate` will be called again once things are being merged, but if it does, you will skip setting `first`. This is not your problem at the moment since you do not have multiple (or any) `NULL` values, but it is a potential problem for real data sets.
   3. In the case where both instances have been called on non-`NULL` values, both will at least have `first` set, and maybe `last` (or maybe not). By overwriting the current instance with the incoming `Group`, you could be losing the real `first` value, losing the real `last` value.
2. As @DanGuzman mentioned in his answer, there is no guaranteed ordering of User-Defined Aggregates (the `IsInvariantToOrder` property of the `SqlUserDefinedAggregate` attribute is ignored / unused). And, as he noted, you will need to pass in the `Date_Time` value in order to handle this aspect of the operation manually. However, it won't be used in the `Terminate` method. It will instead be used to compare to two new variables: `firstDate` and `lastDate`, initialized to a future and past, respectively (this will likely require changing the `Format` to `UserDefined` and then adding custom `Read` and `Write` methods -- unless you can store the full `DateTime` values as ticks, perhaps).

   - Get rid of the `counter` variable
   - In the `Accumulate` method, you will need to:

     1. IF the incoming `Date_Value` against `firstDate`. If it is before to `firstDate` then store this new value as `firstDate` and store `Value` as `first`, ELSE
     2. IF the incoming `Date_Value` against `lastDate`. If it is after to `lastDate` then store this new value as `lastDate` and store `Value` as `last`, ELSE do nothing
   - In the `Merge` method, do a similar comparison for `firstDate` between both instances and keep the earlier one (date and value). Do the same with `lastDate` and keep the later one (date and value). (Note: these changes should fix all of the `Merge` issues noted above in # 1)
   - The `terminate` method shouldn't change

For what it's worth, I ran the code exactly as you have posted in the question, and it returns the expected value, using the following test query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test ([Date_Time] DATETIME, [Value] FLOAT);

-- TRUNCATE TABLE #Test;
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('2018-03-29 09:30:02.533', 6771);
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('2018-03-29 10:26:23.557', 6779);
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('2018-03-29 13:12:04.550', 6787);
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('2018-03-29 13:55:44.560', 6795);


SELECT dbo.SUBT([Value])
FROM   #Test;
-- 24
```

So, if you are still having issues, then you will need to post more info, such as the test query (and maybe table) that you are using. But even if it appears to work, like it does on my system, it still has the potential ordering problem and will need to be updated as noted above regardless.

---

Other notes:

1. In the `Accumulate` method you have `(double)Value`. There is no need to cast the incoming parameter. All `Sql*` types have a `Value` property that returns the value in the native .NET type. In this case, just use `Value.Value`. That isn't great for readability, so consider changing the name of the input paramter ;-).
2. You never use the value of `counter`, so why increment it? You could instead just use a `bool`, and set it to `true` here. Setting it to true for each non-`NULL` value will not change the operation. However, this is a moot point since you truly need to set either `first` or `last` in each call to this UDA, based on the current `Date_Time` value.